# Copy/paste contents from a file into multiple tmux ssh sessions

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I have a file with a list of IP addresses for example called IP_LIST. my goal is to iterate through each IP and copy that to multiple tmux panes (1 IP per pane). The script below assumes that you are already in a tmux session. I'm having difficulty copying the IPs to the clipboard then having it pasted to each pane. im sure i need to incorporate tmux-buffer somehow. I would hope someone can point me in the right direction.

currently, the script does the following:

1. reads the IP_LIST file
2. Splits the panes based on the number of IP addresses.
3. ssh`s into the designated host. (i have Host configured "mc" as my default in /etc/ssh
   /config)

```
while IFS= read -r ip || [[ -n "$ip" ]]; do

    echo "$ip" | xclip -selection clipboard  
    tmux split-window -v; tmux send-keys "ssh mc" ; tmux send-keys "KPEnter"
    tmux bind C-b run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
done < "$1"
```

IP_list

```
1.2.3.4
4.3.2.1
6.7.8.9
```

can be run with the following:

```
./tmux_ip_script IP_LIST
```

EDIT: Updated the script with a tmux buffer. However, does not copy to each pane.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [xpanes](https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes).

```
$ cat IP_list
1.2.3.4
4.3.2.1
6.7.8.9
$ xpanes -c 'ssh {}' $(cat IP_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar. I use it with another function that has IP addresses as the first column.  I call mine "so.sh" (for ssh open).  It uses send-keys.  In this case you would use `cat <myfile> | so.sh` and it would open an new tmux window with a new pane with an ssh session for each.  Maybe it could be modified for your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
# so.sh => ssh open
# takes piped input, creats a new tmux window, and then  
# uses first column to open a new tmux pane with an ssh session to each pane

if ! [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  echo "This must be run from a tmux session"
  exit 0
fi

base="so" 


ipList=""
while read -r data; do
  ipList+=$(echo $data | awk '{print $1}')" "
done 

tmux new-window -n $base

p=1

for ip in $ipList; do
  if [[ $p > 1 ]]; then 
      tmux splitw -v -t "$base" # vertical split
    tmux select-layout -t "$base" even-vertical
  fi
    tmux send-keys -t "$base.$p" "ssh $ip" enter
  ((p++))
done
```

Comment: `tmux send-keys -t <target_window>.<pane_number> ` is probably the key part for you.